# C array, preset with huge values?

Tags: c, arrays

Here is my C code which is giving me problems:

```
int main(){
int Steps = 100;
double Time = 10;
double h = Time/Steps;

double r[Steps+1];
double phi[Steps+1];
double u[Steps+1];
double v[Steps+1];

r[0]=0;
phi[0]=0;
u[0]=0;
v[0]=0;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("results.dat", "w");

if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Could not open results.dat \n");
    exit(0);
}

int i;
for(i=0; i<Steps; i++){
    fprintf(fp, "%f, %f \n",r[i], phi[i]);
}

fclose(fp);
}
```

When I look into the dat file almost all of the entries are 0.0 except for a few which have huge numbers. It seems so random and I haven't said to assign any values to anything yet. Does anyone know why these numbers are appearing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask for large blocks of memory on the stack, but make no checks or assignments for their value, and thus get whatever happened to be in memory. I'd expect that some bytes end up having higher-value bits set, giving you "random" data in your reads and writes. Take a look at `memset(3)` and `malloc(3)`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it worked like that. I will look into your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else mentioned as well you have your array's on the stack. These stack variables are not initialized and will reflect the contents of the stack where they are allocated. Either move them out of main and make them global or intialize them e.g int r[10] = {0}; or calloc/malloc,memset the array.